# Add a [Call on Teams] button

Tags: html, microsoft-teams

Is it possible to add a [Call] button in a web page which when clicked will open the teams chat page for a specific person.

The users who are consuming this web page are corporate users and I can assume that all of them have the Teams with corporate account installed on their machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible using [Deep Linking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links), specifically [linking to a Chat](https://teams.microsoft.com/l/meetup-join/19%3ameeting_MzdiNzE4NjMtM2NlYi00MTQ1LWIxMDQtZTM0NDhjNTE1MGNh%40thread.v2/0?context=%7b%22Tid%22%3a%22a623a8d2-b751-46b9-85e0-78e7c8582eb1%22%2c%22Oid%22%3a%22e2210393-c0a3-49f8-9e86-830e31729173%22%7d).

Comment: Can you please add the code as well like exactly how you have implemented "Linking to a Chat" triggers a call directly?

Comment: So it doesn't actually start the call, it just links to the chat with the person, per your original post. If this is for an external user (you mention it's on a webpage, so maybe it's for e.g. a customer?) then Azure Communication Services might work (it integrates with internal users on Teams). See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/overview